# In AWS how do I configure the Inbox Preview Text using the SES API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm currently doing this inside a Lambda function (many lines of code omitted):

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var ses = new aws.SES();

    var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: toAddresses,                     
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Data: html
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: subject
            }
       },
       Source: source
    };

    var email = ses.sendEmail(params, (error, data) => {
    });
};
```

When I receive the email inside Microsoft Outlook, it shows this text underneath the subject:

*(Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body.*

**How do I configure that text to be something else?**

I can't find it in the [SendEmail API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html).  I tried searching for that text and didn't see anything on Google, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It looks like the Inbox Preview text in Outlook will be based on the `HTML` or `Text` that is set.**

Experimenting with the `Text` property from Michael's answer help me figure this out.  In my HTML I found out I had this:

```
<!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
    (Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body.
</div>
```

Changing that solved my problem.  *facepalm*  (Someone else gave me the HTML to send and I didn't look through it carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the SDK for this (I wrote my own), but based on the API docs, it should look something like this:

```
Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: html
+           },
+           Text: {
+               Data: 'add this section and put the preview data here'
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: subject
        }
   },
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Body.html

Comment: Thanks! That ended up helping me figure it out.